# Enable/disable mesh renderer of multiple gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I enable/disable mesh renderer of multiple gameobjects when the player enters in a collider? This is my code but it doesn't works.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SueloManager : MonoBehaviour {

private GameObject suelo;

void Start ()
{
    suelo = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("SueloWireframe");
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {

        suelo.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = false;
        Debug.Log ("Oculta suelo");

    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {

        suelo.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = true;
        Debug.Log ("Aparece suelo");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple gameobjects" and please explain what you mean also mean by "does not work". Do you see the log?

Comment: Learn to use the language before learning a game engine. You're assigning the result of `FindGameObjectsWithTag`, which is an array of `GameObject`, to a variable that can only hold one. And after that, you would need a loop, to actually perform some operation in all of them. I agree with Programmer, show the errors, show what you've tried, explain expected results.

Comment: @Programmer No error appears in console but when the player enters in collider only one object disables.

Comment: This is not true. That code will not compile. It should give you compile time error. While I have provided you an answer, I suggest you do what @Kroltan mentioned. Learn basic C# before moving on. Most people jump to Unity and miss the basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindGameObjectWithTag` returns a single GameObject and `FindGameObjectsWithTag` returns array of GameObject. Just like *Kroltan*  mentioned, you have to change `suelo` to an array then use loop to enable and disable all of them. Having the loop in a simple re-usable function should simplify this. Look at the `EnableRenderer` function in the solution below.

```
private Renderer[] sueloRenderers;

void Start()
{
    GameObject[] suelo = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SueloWireframe");
    sueloRenderers = new Renderer[suelo.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < sueloRenderers.Length; i++)
    {
        sueloRenderers[i] = suelo[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        EnableRenderer(sueloRenderers, false);
        Debug.Log("Oculta suelo");

    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        EnableRenderer(sueloRenderers, true);
        Debug.Log("Aparece suelo");

    }
}

void EnableRenderer(Renderer[] rd, bool enable)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rd.Length; i++)
    {
        rd[i].enabled = enable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I'm a beginner and I'm learning slowly.